# Calling function to only one div of a certain class using pure JS

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach, this, dom-node

as part of my learning process as front end developer, I have decided to produce a product without jQuery and instead use vanilla JavaScript to do all my interactions.

I want to call a function onClick and retrieve the positioning of only the DOM node I clicked which is part of a class. However I don't know how this would be done in pure JavaScript. Basically I want to replicate what $(this) does in jQuery.

Here is my code below so far:

```
function expand(name) {
    var elem = document.querySelectorAll(name)

for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var rect = elem[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".box").onclick = expand(this)
```

Thanks in advance and any other possible solutions to the problem are much appreciated.

Comment: For a start, this line is wrong: `document.querySelectorAll(".box").onclick = expand(this)` you are running the function `expand` and assigning it's return value (`undefined`) to `onclick`. The second problem is that `querySelectorAll` will return a collection. You need to index the collection to access the individual elements so you can assign an `onclick` handler.

Comment: This [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/) might prove useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a *NodeList*. This is *Array-like* and needs to be iterated over
- You can use `this` inside your handler to refer to the node the handler is attached to
- The vanilla way to listen for an event is [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), this only attaches a handler for one event type at a time so if you want to be able to use multiple you'll need to loop here again (you didn't do this in your example but jQuery lets you do this)

```
function expand() {
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
}

function nodeListOn(list, type, handler, useCapture) {
    var i, t;
    type = type.split(/s+/);
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        for (t = 0; t < type.length; ++t) {
            list[i].addEventListener(type[t], handler, useCapture);
        }    
    }
}

var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
nodeListOn(nodes, 'click', expand);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    element.onclick = expand.bind(element);
});
```

This will result in the `this` scope being set to the element being clicked on.

Comment: `nodeList.forEach` is _undefined_ (you'll need to borrow it from _Array_ if you want to use it)

Comment: wow, I have been using JS for about 3 years now and never knew `querySelectorAll` does not return an Array. I have been spoiled by frameworks and such :) updated.